# SHA1 Python to C# conversion

Tags: c#, python, cryptography, sha1

I have following piece python code that I'm trying to covert to C#. The result of C# implementation differs from the python. Can anyone explain what this code is doing, please?
Any suggestions on converting to C#?

Input is: user@me.com

Python Code:

```
def encode_username(u):
    d = hashlib.sha1(u).digest()
    return base64.b32encode(d).lower()
```

Result:`'2hg7ic5ttw4cgfo5kfnjhtqwbq73l6rl'`

My C# code:

```
    string EncodeUsername(string username)
    {
        var sh = SHA1.Create();
        var bytes = sh.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username));
        return Base32.ToBase32String(bytes);
    }
```

Result: `'D1CDF40BB39DB82315DD515A93CE160C3FB5FA2B'`

Base32 reference: http://www.atrevido.net/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=debdd47c-9d15-4a2f-a796-99b0449aa8af

Comment: `Base32.ToBase32String` is not standard, can you show us that implementation? It could depend on ways bytes are being got between the two languages (i.e. encoding), or how the string is constructed, or something else entirely, of course.

Comment: Maybe you have an encoding problem in the string Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username) returns the current ANSI Encoding of the pc, it might not return the same bytes as the python one.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Updated my question

Comment: From the linked article on the .NET library: "Note that this does not conform to the Base32 standard encoding, but uses it's own set of characters..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you linked to atrevido.net can't generate the output you described (`D1CD...`), since that code doesn't use the character `1` at all (see it's `ValidChars` constant, which uses a *very* non-standard base32 character map, and among other things lacks a `1` and a `0`).

In fact, the output string you gave for C# contains only the characters `0-9A-F`, which makes me thing it's hexidecimal. Going on that, the python output of `hashlib.sha1('user@me.com').hexdigest().upper()` is in fact the string you received from C# ... `D1CDF40BB39DB82315DD515A93CE160C3FB5FA2B`.

So the problem is that whatever code you're using under .Net isn't doing base32 encoding of any type, but base16 / hexidecimal. You'll want to use hex under python, or a real base32 implementation under .Net.

(Also, as others have suggested, you should use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`, else you will get inconsistent behavior across different computers).

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid** using `Encoding.Default` (can you tell what it is?) and use the one you know the other (Python) part is using, e.g. `Encoding.UTF8`

Otherwise we might need to see your code for `Base32.ToBase32String` to see if the input or output differs.

Answer (score 1):

#### C#

```
private static SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

private static string CalculateSHA1(string text, Encoding enc)
{
    byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
    return BitConverter.ToString(SHA.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");
}
```

#### Python

```
def encode_username(u):
return hashlib.sha1(u.encode('utf-8'));
```

Comment: this is what I have got: C# result :D1CDF40BB39DB82315DD515A93CE160C3FB5FA2B

Python result:2hg7ic5ttw4cgfo5kfnjhtqwbq73l6rl the text is: user@me.com

Comment: @Prashant - Did you try the encoding: Encoding.UTF8